# Is there a method of executing a command then continue the program without command termination

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Hi I am trying to create a function which remotely executes my packet sniffing script on my raspberry pi using paramiko and ssh.

```
def startPacketReceiver():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(RECV_IP_ADDRESS, username="pi", password="raspberry")
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo gcc Code/test.c && sudo ./a.out")
    print("Done")
```

The test.c file is the packet sniffing script. It will only terminate with a CTRL-C (or equivalent method). It does not terminate naturally/eventually.

I want to be able to start the receiver and then quit the receiver e.g:

```
startPacketReceiver()
...
stopPacketReceiver()
```

Currently when I run the python script I never get the "Done" print message, meaning that the program is hung on the exec_command and will not continue until it is terminated.

**Additional Info**

The test.c file loops infinitely, essentially:

```
while(1)
{
    saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
    //fprintf(stderr,"%d",data_size);
    if(data_size <0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to get packet\n");
        printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Now process the packet
    ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
}
```

and so to stop it you must CTRL-C it.

Comment: That's strange, the `SSClient.exec_command` is not blocking. What if you do something like `sleep 60 && ls`. Does it also hang for 60 seconds?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The program waits 60 seconds before continuing.

Comment: "without resorting to threading"  If you want to do 2 things at once, you need some form of concurrency.  Your basic choices are multi-threaded, or multi-process. Spawning a second process could certainly be viewed as "resorting to threading", so it's not really clear what you want to do.  You can either run a separate thread in the same process, or create new threads in a new process.

Comment: `if(data_size <0 )` : if read() or recv() return -1, you should check errno. It could be EINTR/EAGAIN

Comment: What kind of system and shell do you have on the server? On Ubuntu and bash I get "Done" immediately with `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sleep 60 && ls"); print("Done");`

Comment: @Using a raspbian on raspberry pi 4. I am running the python on my windows 10 based laptop.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Could you show me an example of threading in python using my problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `sudo` part in `exec_command` does not wait for a passwort?

Comment: @BastianVenthur I have to run the command as sudo or high privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your password to the `sudo` command. Please enable `tty` mode for executing your command by passing `get_pty = True` argument to `exec_command` function call. And then you need to pass your password through `ssh_stdin` file interface.

```
def startPacketReceiver():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(RECV_IP_ADDRESS, username="pi", password="raspberry")
    ssh.stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("gcc Code/test.c && sudo ./a.out", get_pty=True)
    print("raspberry", ssh_stdin) # Your password for sudo command
    print("Done")
    return ssh, ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr
```

And then you can write your `stopPacketReceiver` to send Ctrl-C signal.

```
def stopPacketReceiver(ssh, ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr):
    print('\x03', file=ssh_stdin) # Send Ctrl-C signal
    print(ssh_stdout.read()) #print the stdout
    print(ssh_stderr.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at [daemon(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)

Then you can capture SIGNALS or reopen standard input.
Depends on what you would like to do with your python script.
(If you don't want to use any python any python library other than sys and os)

**EDIT:**

I am pretty sure when the python script will terminate the ssh connection will obviously close and so any program running on that tty by the user who initiated the connection will be terminated.
For that reason your c program needs to be daemonized and may need
to have its uid and/or euid changed.

Despite that i tried to reproduce your code and I ran into a similar problem: the python script was running the command then print "Done"
but as I tried to read stdout, the entire script was pause.
I think it was waiting for the script return status.
So i did the following changes:

```
try:
    port = '22'
  
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  
    client.connect('<host_name>', port=22, username='<username>',
                   password='<password>')
  
    chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.get_pty()
    chan.exec_command("cd <script_directory>;\
                ; gcc test.c; ./a.out")
    while True:
        print(chan.recv(1024))
  
finally:
    client.close()
```

The while loop here is to get output of the c program.
But if you close the python script the c program will follow.
I did not dug to much into this library.

**EDIT 2:**

Look up [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

if you don't want to use de daemon approach.